How to programatically call bcdboot?
How to programatically call the following bcdboot command using C++ WINAPI?
bcdboot O:\Windows /s O:

I have found this class but nothing yet about bcdboot specifically.

Does it have to be the Windows API specifically? Why not the C++ standard std::system function? What are you really trying to do? What is the actual problem you need to solve?

@Someprogrammerdude what do you mean "standard system function"? I'm not trying to solve anything, im asking if theres any winapi to achieve the same, i learn way more about when digging into these apis than simple running it on cmd.

It means just launching an external process to do so. Check the documentation for std::system for details.

@Jabu AFAIK, there is no single Win32 API that does what bcdboot does. Just call it with std::system(), eg: std::system("bcdboot O:\\Windows /s O:");

Just opened it up in IDA; there is no API, it implements everything internally.
